# What is a good database structure for tracking who has read which messages?

Tags: database, algorithm

In a messaging forum such as Stack Overflow, what is an efficient way to store the data to track who has read which messages?

If there are `m` messages and `n` users, is it possible to have a worst case of less than `m` * `n` bits?

Comment: To the second part of your question: Short answer, no. Long answer, nooooooo.

Comment: Even though `m * n` bit field approach will be space effecient, i do not know of any effecient querying system on that data. Especially if users and messages increase/decrease over time.

Comment: In a nosql approach, you track each user view activity under one message record. Lookup any message, you have all the users that viewed it

Comment: This sounds like an interview-type question. There are many ways to solve this problem, each using different assumption for which type of queries you want to efficiently support, the amount of data we're talking about and how many resources you have available for partitioning or replication. Seems too broad.

Comment: This is not for an interview.  This is for a real problem I have.  `n` is about 600 and `m` would be in thousands, say, up to 100,000 for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with a classic `READ_MESSAGES` table.

```
-----FK---------FK------------------------------------
|  msg_id  |  user_id  | read_timestamp  |  blah...
------------------------------------------------------
 \========PK==========/
```

This will work well upto a million rows or so. Then insertions will become a pain. If we use something like MySQL, then we will need to have an artificial autoincrement primary key.

```
-------------------FK---------FK----------------------------------
|  autoinc_pk |  msg_id  |  user_id  | read_timestamp  |  blah...
------------------------------------------------------------------
\=====PK=====/ \===UNIQUE=NOT=NULL===/
```

This will capture our data fine, but may not be optimal for querying. We have two possible ways:

1. Given `message id` show which or how many users have read it. `SELECT msg_id, COUNT(user_id) FROM read_messages WHERE msg_id='123'`
2. Given `user id` show which or how many messages have been read. `SELECT user_id, COUNT(msg_id) FROM read_messages WHERE user_id='456'`

Of course system will need to perform both types of queries, but if it does one type of query way more than other then we can tweak the design to make those queries a little faster. This is done by altering the order of the columns in the `UNIQUE-NOT-NULL` key. Idea is out of the two columns, put first the column with the given value, in other words put first the column which appears in the `WHERE` clause.

So, if we find the system doing more Type-1 queries then Type-2 queries, we will have columns ordered as `{msg_id, user_id}` otherwise we order it as `{user_id, msg_id}`. Remember, when we do a `WHERE` query on a multicolumn key, the first column favors speed.

If we do find our application favoring one type of queries way more over the other, we can go further and partition/shard the table horizontally on the column in `WHERE` clause. In databases like Cassandra or DynamoDB, it could be the partition key.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I see the main use as finding out which messages a user has seen, so as to unhighlight them in the "index" pages.

Comment: Why not only store records for *unread* messages?  It seems more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a really scalable solution and for some reason simple sql table does not work for you l, here is alternative with DynamoDB:

Have a table with primary key of user ID and range key of message ID. Also create a Global Secondary Index with primary key as Message ID and range key as User ID. Now you can easily perform any types of queries you might want (ex: get messages read by user X, get users who read message Y, or did user X read message Y). This solution is scalable and has constant, predictable speed. Disadvantage is that it is probably going to be more expensive than sql.